# batch create junction link of firefox profile with option to exclude some subfolder and file

Tags: batch-file, firefox

I am new in cmd batch file coding. However i want to make a junction link of firefox profile using mklink /j. to do this i tried this code below:

```
@echo off :Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim @echo off

:: Run this script with elevation  call :RequestAdminElevation "%~dpfs0" %* || goto:eof 

set  source = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default
set "target=c:\targe"
set "exclude=%temp%\exclude.txt"    pause

(
    rem exclude files/dires with these strings into full path
    echo .txt
    echo pipe.cmd

    rem escaped backslash and initial and final quotes to avoid partial matches
    echo "c:\\source\\directory\\something.txt"

    rem exclude thisNot file/directory from source directory
    echo "%source:\=\\%\\thisNot"

)> "%exclude%"

forfiles /P "%source%" /C "cmd /c (echo @path|findstr /i /v /g:"%exclude%" >nul) && if @isdir==TRUE (mklink /d \"%target%\\\"@file @path) else (mklink \"%target%\\\"@file @path)"  del "%exclude%" > nul pause &goto:eof
```

But when i run this code it shows cannot find the path specified. That means it cannot locate firfox profile folder.

i tried it with other url this time it works. So please give me a solution.

Comment: Can you try adding pauses to see which line specifically gives the error? This might give us a better idea where to look.

Comment: @Dennis van Gils  i tried it by pauses . CMD shows - "ERROR: Value for '/p' option cannot be empty. " & Type ''FORFILES/?'' for usages.

Comment: Can you try using `set  "source=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"`

Comment: Also, your target contains c:\targe, is this a misspelling?

Comment: @Dennis van Gils yes i tried , it shows ERROR: The directory name is invalid.

Comment: when i try this code in a separate batch files is runs without error. say- FOR /D %%G in ("%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default") DO Echo ***Found folder: %%G

Answer (score 0):

Forfiles doesn't support files in the /p parameter, instead it uses /m for that, so you should use

```
set  "source=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"
```

and

```
forfiles /P "%source%" /M "*.default" /C ...
```

Comment: i run with the change you advice. It shows - ''ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'path|findstr' & Type ''FORFILES/?'' for usages. does it causes because the path is a relative path?

Comment: @ Dennis van Gils - please give me a solution what is the alternative way to use instead of forfiles?